# How to range over bson.D primitive.A slice mongo-go-driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

My data structure is

```
{
    _id: ObjectID,
    ... 
    fields: [
     { name: "Aryan" },
     { books : [ 1,2,3 ] },
    ] 
}
```

In our application a user can define his own **fields** data structure but with a key value structure. So, we had no way of knowing the structure of the data.

So in our document struct we had

```
type Document struct {
    Fields map[string]interface{} 
}
```

as the second parameter returned by mongo was primitive.A ( []interface{} under the hood ), the individual item could have been an array, map, anything.
But we couldn't range over that for it being.

How can I get the individual values like the book ids [1,2,3] or the name value "Aryan" ?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of attempts to solving this, I was at a state where my current element it self is an interface{} ( [1,2,3] in this case ) and I couldn't get the individual 1,2,3s.

But finally managed to solve it

```
for k, val := range doc.Fields {

  v := reflect.ValueOf(val)
  
      switch reflect.TypeOf(t).Kind() {
      case reflect.Slice:
      // getting the individual ids   

        for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
           fmt.Println(v.Index(i))
       }

      case reflect.String:

      default: 
      // handle 
     }          
}
```

Note: v.Index(i) returns a data type of **Value** .

to change the data type

```
v.Index(i).Interface().(string) // string 
v.Index(i).Interface().(float64) // float
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should avoid working with `interface{}` type since it's very error prone and the compiler can't help you. The idiomatic way is to define a struct for your model with BSON tags like [in this example](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang--mongodb--modeling-documents-with-go-data-structures)`

```
type MyType struct {
    ID     primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Fields []Field            `bson:"fields,omitempty"`
}

type Field struct {
    Name string `bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Books []int `bson:"books,omitempty"`
}
```

Field here is defined as the reunion of all possible fields which again is not ideal but at least the compiler can help you and developers know what to expect from the database document.

Comment: Agree. 
But eventually mongo driver was giving me a primitive.A type field despite what I give. So I had to fall back to interface eventually.

And secondly, about your example, 
my field struct had different schema, it wasn't name and books

it was key value pair where a value can be array/string/numeric so the Field struct won't work.